# Append log details in file rather in console in liferay 6.2 ga2

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

In liferay 6.2 to append log details in file instead of console i m inserting 2nd and 3rd line in log4j.properties file(please check line no below) and commenting the 4th line which is present in log4j.properties file by default . but fail to find log details in file. is this right way to configure ??.. if anyone knows solution for this please do reply .

my log4j.properties file look something like this.

1. log4j.rootLogger=INFO, CONSOLE[image]
2. log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
3. log4j.appender.CONSOLE.File= E:\lrportal\workspace\liferay6.2\liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2\tomcat-7.0.42\logs\log-today.log
4. ## log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
5. log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout
6. log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c{1}:%L] %m%n

Answer (score 0):

## Define the root logger with appender file

log4j.rootLogger = INFO, FILE

## Define the file appender

log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender

## Set the name of the file

log4j.appender.FILE.File=${log}/log.out

## Set the immediate flush to true (default)

log4j.appender.FILE.ImmediateFlush=true

## Set the threshold to debug mode

log4j.appender.FILE.Threshold=debug

## Set the append to false, overwrite

log4j.appender.FILE.Append=false

## Define the layout for file appender

log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n

check below link for details
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_logging_files.htm

Comment: log4j.rootLogger = ALL, FILE
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=E:/test.log
log4j.appender.FILE.ImmediateFlush=true
log4j.appender.FILE.Threshold=debug
log4j.appender.FILE.Append=true
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c{1}:%L]  %m%n

Comment: Hi thanks for your solution but still logs are not appended to file and above code is content of my log4j.properties file

Comment: can you please share your log file

Comment: log4j.rootLogger = ALL, FILE
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=E:/test.log
log4j.appender.FILE.ImmediateFlush=true
log4j.appender.FILE.Threshold=debug
log4j.appender.FILE.Append=true
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c{1}:%L]  %m%n

please check my log4j.properties file

Comment: you can also check the snapshot of log4j.properties file